# error when trying to makemigrations/migrate in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

i just made made a new project and when i try to to run a command like makemigration, migrate or runserver it gives the following error, i've followed a tutorial video just as he did it but it didn't give him an error but it gave me an error.

**here is the error i get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 100, in check_url_settings
    value = getattr(settings, name)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telsem.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\kaleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\upbeat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\kaleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\kaleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telsem.settings'
```

**here are my installed apps in settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

***here is the project structure***

```
kaleb(folder)
|  api(folder)
|  |  migrations(folder)
|  | __init__.py
|  |  admin.py
|  | apps.py
|  |  models.py
|  |  tests.py
|  |  urls.py
|  |  views.py
|  kaleb(folder)
|  | __init__.py
|  | settings.py
|  | urls.py
|  | wsgi.py
manage.py
```

manage.py:

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'telsem.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
```

Comment: Show your project structure.

Comment: i can't upload a picture on this site, is their any other why i can send the project structure

Comment: You can add pictures if you edit your post.

Comment: i edited in a structure i made with text.

Comment: Have u used `telsem.settings` in anywhere?

Comment: no that's what is confusing me i didn't even create or use a file named as telsem.setting, i didn't even write code that says telsem.setting

Comment: but the name of the project folder is telsem.

Comment: It should be kaleb

Comment: i just replaced the name telsem with kaleb for the question however everything regarding the name is telsem.

Comment: @AllinOne please show the contents of your `manage.py` file of your project and the `apps.py` file of app `kaleb`

Comment: this is the apps.py :

`from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
`

Comment: ill edit the question to include the manage.py code.

Comment: i noticed this: def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'telsem.settings')
    try: but is their another way to point to the settings.py file

Comment: It looks like you changed your project name midway? Anyway fix that line by changing it to `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'kaleb.settings')`. There should also be an `apps.py` in the app `kaleb` which might need fixing.

Comment: it worked!!, i had an incorrect path to the settings.py, thanks yall.